# Rotating a bottle Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

I'm trying to spin a bottle (I'm calculating the first pos and end pos of the mouse) and apply forces to it according to the 'swipe' length/time. After the initial swipe, the bottle should keep rotating based on the force of the swipe, and then stop after few seconds.

I hope you could help me here. Thanks!

[bottle interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIWs8.jpg)

This is what I tried to do, but it doesn't work well:

```
public Rigidbody bottle;
 bool isSwiping;
 Touch thisTouch;
 Vector2 origPos;
 Vector2 endPos;
 float touchSpeed;
 Vector3 Torque;
 float timeStart; float timeEnd;


 void OnMouseDown()
 {
     timeStart = Time.time;
     origPos = Input.mousePosition;
 }

 void OnMouseDrag()
 {


     isSwiping = true;


 }

 void OnMouseUp()
 {
     if (isSwiping)
     {
         timeEnd = Time.time;
         endPos = Input.mousePosition;
         Vector2 deltaPosition = endPos - origPos;
         touchSpeed = deltaPosition.magnitude / (timeEnd-timeStart);
         Torque = new Vector3(touchSpeed * 500f, 0, 0);
     }
 }



 void Update()
 {

 }


 void FixedUpdate()
 {
     if (isSwiping) bottle.AddRelativeTorque(Torque);
 }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "doesn't work well" means in this case? Please edit your question with additional information and visual aids as needed.

Comment: May be for swipe you try use Input.GetAxis("Horizonal") for detect speed change X coordinate mouse and Input.GetAxis("Vertical") for Y?

Comment: @Serlite I mean it's not rotating, doing nothing really.

Comment: @V.Borodinov 
I used  GetAxis, but only to drag the bottle, it doesn't rotate the bottle as I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Try use this code:

```
public Rigidbody bottle;
 bool isSwiping;
 Touch thisTouch;
 Vector2 origPos;
 Vector2 endPos;
 float touchSpeed;
 Vector3 Torque;
 float timeStart; float timeEnd;


 void OnMouseDown()
 {
     timeStart = Time.time;
     origPos = Input.mousePosition;
 }

 void OnMouseUp()
 {
     timeEnd = Time.time;
     endPos = Input.mousePosition;
     Vector2 deltaPosition = endPos - origPos;
     touchSpeed = deltaPosition.magnitude / (timeEnd-timeStart);
     Torque = new Vector3(touchSpeed * 500f, 0, 0);
     isSwiping = true;
 }

 void FixedUpdate()
 {
     if (isSwiping) bottle.AddRelativeTorque(Torque);
 }
```

Comment: Great! It works! one thing though before I accept the answer,
the bottle keep spinning without stopping. how can I lower the speed over-time?
when I spin the bottle, it should spin for a certain time depends on my swipe. is it possible?

Comment: Yes I did that, it stops directly, without lowering the rotation speed over time.

Comment: Change Torque value, example Torque = Vector3.MoveTowards(Torque, Vector3.zero, Time.deltaTime * 3) in FixedUpdate